# how do you restrict the length of a tkinter text widget in python by blocking the latest character entered?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, widget

I am trying to limit the amount of characters in a tkinter text widget or entry widget (either widget type is fine) in Python in a very specific way.  I have a solution with a text widget that is close:

```
string =  self.text.get("1.0","end-1c")
if len(string) >= 5:
    self.text.delete('1.0', "end-1c")
    string = string[:-1]
    self.quantity_entry.insert(END, string)
```

But the above code does the following: If I enter 123456, it turns it the content into 12346.  It chops off the last character of the existing field (5), and then places the last character typed (6) at the end.  So it becomes 12346.

What I want is 12345 to stay 12345, meaning the existing 12345 string should stay as-is, and any new characters effectively get blocked from being appended.  Is there a way to do this?

I tried using:

```
self.text.configure(state="disabled")
```

This does block subsequent characters from being inserted, so 12345 stays 12345. But this locks up the field from future editing. Even when subsequently try to use:

```
self.text.configure(state="normal")
```

the field stays locked. I want the user to be able to edit the field if they hit the five character limit.

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you really want here is tkinter validation: you can write a function that will be called whenever the user tries to edit the text, where you’ll be passed the proposed new string (or the existing string, or both, or a variety of different options), and you can accept or reject the change. Would that do what you want? If so, I can find you a good duplicate question with a great answer.

Comment: thanks abarnert.  i played around with validation, but i was still getting the last character entered appended (which is not what i want).  i figured out the solution, which i posted below.

Comment: The solution for an entry widget could be very different than for a text widget. Which one do you prefer? The entry widget has an option specifically for validating the data.

Comment: thanks Bryan. i was happy to get either to work. but now that i see the code problem was with key vs keyrelease, i am going to try to use the entry widget. it has validate, and the delete syntax is a  little cleaner compared to the text widget.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much neater to trace a variable. Then it wouldn't even blink briefly on the screen. You could package into a neat subclass like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Lotfi(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, max_len=5, **kwargs):
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.max_len = max_len
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)
        self.old_value = ''
        self.var.trace('w', self.check)

    def check(self, *args):
        if len(self.get()) <= self.max_len:
            self.old_value = self.get() # accept change
        else:
            self.var.set(self.old_value) # reject change

#demo code:
window = tk.Tk()
ent=Lotfi(window, max_len=5)
ent.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, Novel.  i was interested in trace, but i heard it was deprecated.  but i didn't find any hard evidence on that. have you seen anything authoritative on trace being phased out?

Comment: Trace is not depreciated and I haven't heard anyone say that there's plans to depreciate it.

Comment: thanks, Novel.  I did my own version of the check method without *args in the signature, and it didn't work.  then i put *args in, and it worked.  why is *args needed?  i'm not feeding the method any parameters when i am calling it.  it must be something internal to tkinter.

Comment: Yeah, tkinter's trace sends 3 useless arguments when calling the function. Just add `print(args)` to see them if you are curious.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.  In the .bind method, I needed to use

```
"<KeyRelease>"
```

rather than

```
"<Key>"
```

Then, as a minor edit, >=5 needed to be changed to > 5.  Now it works.  When I enter 123456 it very briefly shows 123456 on the screen, but then quickly chops off the 6, so it goes back to 12345.  Yay!

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very old but thought it could help some folk out.

Been looking for a very elegant solution to this problem. But haven't found one yet. So thought I'd post my messy one.

If you find this useful please up vote, Also if you have ideas on how I can communicate more clearly I'd love that as well.

Here is 'an' answer. But it would help if you explained why you chose to write the code you did so I could better direct your method of thinking about arriving at a solution.

```
# IMPORT MODULES AND ALIAS THEM
import tkinter as tk

# This is a place holder to self.quantity_entry.insert(END, string) just to 
# simulate the call to some other object
def OtherTextWidget(string):
    print( f"{text1.index(tk.END)}, {string}" )

# This is the 'meat' of your solution that limits the input
def Restrict(e=None):
    print(e.type) # just to proof that we are pressing a key

    # If for some unknown reason this function gets called on key-release, it will 
    # terminate the function. Because it will break our desired behavior.
    if int(e.type) == 3: 
            return

    # The 'widget.bind()' event argument pass a reference to the widget that
    # called it. Se we use that here to get the text from the caller 
    # "text1.bind()" as event.widget.get() note we have aliased 'event' as 'e'
    # inside the function space.

    # Get text from start to the current end length minus the '\n' character
    string =  e.widget.get("1.0","end-1c")

    # If there are 5 or more characters go ahead with the limit
    # Note len() starts at 0, so 4<= is equal to 5+ chars
    if 4 <= len(string):
        # Get the first five characters before the delete
        OtherTextWidget( e.widget.get("1.0","1.5") )
    
        # !!NOTES!!
        # We are lazy and don't want to code a rejection for a 6th character. So 
        # we overwrite the 5th character, the result is the same for less work.
  
        # we are operating during the key press, and the 6th character is not 
        # inserted until the key release. The 5th character is empty if you 
        # debug it after the delete. Again the 5th character will be replaced 
        # by the 6th on the key release.
   
        # delete the 5th character to the '\n', remember we are counting from 0.
        e.widget.delete('1.4', "end-1c")

# TKINTER OBJECTS SETUP:
root = tk.Tk()
text1 = tk.Text(root, width=7, height=1) # 7 chars long, 1 char high
# We give the "entry box" 5 +2 extra character for aesthetics spacing.
# It just looks better with a little room to breath.

text1.pack() # fits the widget in the minimum space within the frame/window
text1.focus_set() # because I'm lazy and I want the cursor already in the widget.

# BIND TEXT WIDGET KEY INPUT EVENT:
# Whenever there is a key press inside the text widget this will fire the 
# Restrict() function with the 'kepress event' argument
# That events data is in key:value pairs and looks something like this:
# <KeyPress event state=Mod1 keysym=1 keycode=97 char='1' x=1959 y=69>
text1.bind('<Key>', Restrict)

# start the tkinter event loop and open a toplevel window
root.mainloop()

# The '<Key>' gives a e.type of 2 or key press/down
# if you use '<KeyRelease>' it gives a e.type of 3 release/up and we will have to 
# change some code around to make it work. But the important difference is it will 
# place the 6th character in the field then delete it, that doesn't look crisp. 
# This is why we are operating on a key press rather than release, because we want 
# to operate on the string before the character is insert into the text widget.
```

Here is the limited commentary code for clarity.
(Updated: I thought it would be nice to have the string that was actually shown so added this release toggle to capture it.)

```
import tkinter as tk

def OtherTextWidget(string):
    print("Key Press Phase:", string)

# Solution - Step 1. toggle full flag
global full #(update)
full = False

# Solution - Step 4. profit
def AfterRestrict(e=None): #(update)
    global full
    if True == full:
        OtherTextWidget( e.widget.get("1.0","1.5") )
        print("Key Release Phase:", e.widget.get("1.0","1.5") )

# Solution - Step 3. limit input
def Restrict(e=None):
    global full #(update)
    string = e.widget.get("1.0","end-1c")
    if 4 <= len(string):
        e.widget.delete('1.4', "end-1c")
        full = True #(update)
    else: #(update)
        full = False

root = tk.Tk()
text1 = tk.Text(root, width=7, height=1)
text1.pack()
text1.focus_set()

# Solution - Step 2. get input event from widget
text1.bind('<Key>', Restrict)
text1.bind('<KeyRelease>', AfterRestrict) #(update)

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for the wordiness very tired, BUT Hope this helps some. :)